# Multicast communication blocked?

Tags: opensuse, multicast

I am struggling to create a multicast communication with basic client and server.
So I looked on the web to find any working example... and they don't work.

I mean the server is waiting for a message that never arrive.

For example, that one : http://www.nmsl.cs.ucsb.edu/MulticastSocketsBook/ (c_send_receive.tar.gz)

So I was wondering if it was Opensuse who would blocked the packets.

```
user@linux-uxnx:~> ip link
```

> 1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
>       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
>
> 2: enp0s25:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
>       link/ether 00:23:18:ed:ef:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> 3: wlp3s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
>       link/ether 00:23:14:3c:7e:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

But it seems that everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you use virtualization, there may not be multicast support in virtualized network and virtual switches or it must be explicitly enabled.

In the past I have encountered this problem when trying to use OSPF multicasts in KVM.